# Where can I find the Maharal's Netivot Olam Online?

Tags: internet, books-generally, maharal

Where can I find a searchable copy of the Maharal's Netivot Olam (Netiv haTorah specifically) online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well wikisource has bits and pieces as far as I can tell, [over here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94). And you can see all 4 seforim [over here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D)).

You can also find it on HebrewBooks.org (pdf's are searchable, but not so good because of OCR) [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/11804) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/14202).